# IntelliJ "Build Project" causes unexpected tests run in multi project builds

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

**Single project**

I run “Build -> Build Project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)” to reload my classes. If I have single project build IntelliJ will execute

```
:classes :testClasses
```

which is fine.

---

**Multi project**

I run “Build -> Build Project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)” to reload my classes. If I have multi project build IntelliJ will execute

```
build :gradle-sub:classes :gradle-sub:testClasses
```

which is causing build to run tests. This is unexpected, slows build or even interrupts it if some test is failed.

---

**Steps to reproduce**

Create project then add subproject and some trivial failing test. "Build Project" command will fail.

---

**Summary**

Is there a way to configure IntelliJ to do not run tests?

Comment: I would say its actually, ok. You can exclude testing but, build depends on compile and test.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175721, we'll investigate and fix it.

Comment: @LazerBanana then if build depends on compile and test. Why test run is excluded in single project or corespongin maven build?